# SMOTE technique not oversampling image dataset

Tags: python, image, imblearn, smote

I am new to imblearn library. I have image dataset belongs to 5 categories,the dataset is highly unbalanced.[image: No.of classes highly unbalanced]
I load images using tensorflow flow.from directory function and use smote function for resampling.

```
img_height, img_width = 224,224
# the no. imgaes to load at each iteration
batch_size = 32
# only rescaling
train_datagen =  ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    vertical_flip=True
)
test_datagen =  ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    vertical_flip=True, 
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True
)
# these are generators for train/test data that will read pictures #found in the defined subfolders of 'data/'
print('Total number of images for "training":')
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
train_data_dir,
target_size = (img_height, img_width),
batch_size = batch_size, 
class_mode = "categorical",shuffle = True
    #,color_mode='grayscale'
)    
smote = SMOTE()
    X_sm, y_sm = smote.fit_resample(train_generator, category_names)
```

the cell start to run and after 30 to 40 mins the jupyter kernel is dead and i got no results. Please help to solve this, i have 16 GB GPU but smote is not running on image dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you can perform [data augmentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/data_augmentationhttps://) on imbalance categories
2. resize them into (28,28) or (32,32) and use [flatten](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) to convert into  784 or 1024 features now you can use SMOTE

hope it will work

Comment: i have medical image dataset if size is (32,32) than it will be very small. currently i am using (224,224) size.